# How to save large data tables?

Tags: c#, mysql, database, wpf

I'm setting up a `Windows` User interface with `WPF`, to capture a large number of user inputs values. The values should be saved with the corresponding variables and some other data. The resulting table would consist of 5 to 10 columns(ID, Name, User Input, variable name, data type...)

Is creating a database (eg using `mySQL`)the right choice, if i want to run the application as an `.exe` on any windows PC?
I know how to implement a `mySQL Database`, but can I use the application on any PC without installing `mySQL`?

Comment: Having a single table with 10 columns and say 10 users might not need a full SQL server setup.  You could just as easily use SQLite and store the data locally, which would not require any extra servers.  You don't give enough information to quantify your requirements.

Comment: That's pretty broad question. You will have to connect to a database on the other side of the internet. Or send the data over the internet to a service But at some point you will need Something.

Comment: I dont wanna send data over the internet. Basically i just want to create one data table with 10 columns and about 400rows. It is fully filled with all data but the user input column. Using the UI i want to fill in the user input and then save a copy of the the list. On every startup of the application the user is asked if he wants to start with the unfilled or a saved filled table. If needed the  user should have the possibilty to print some or all of the data into a textfile .txt

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You need to specify central server that will run MySQL database.

Then use connection string to connect from other PCs to your database.

That's pretty standart..

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a SQL database - using .NET, there are a number of ways to implement this, but I tend to prefer `SQLDataAdapter` if it's an option. See [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/307587/how-to-update-a-database-from-a-dataset-object-by-using-visual-c-2005) for information on how to use it.

Alternatively, if you do not want to use a SQL database, you can turn your `DataTable` or `DataSet` into an XML file using `DataTable.WriteXML()` ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.writexml?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#examples) is more information). You can then read from the file using `DataTable.ReadXML()` later on. Using the XML files allows you to use your application locally.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try sql server Local db which will be in turn mdf file.

You  can create this local db from visual studio "server explorer".But this database will not be on any server it will be limited to your system only.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Sqlite for that exact task.

I don't want to use a remotely stored database on a web server somewhere. I need everyone in the company to have access to the same data source. I have an sqlite database tucked away on the server and its working great. Implementation was an absolute breeze.

All I needed to do was install the Nugget package and create a db file.

You can easily find an sqlite browser on line to help build the tables or you can do it programmatically.

I'm implementing this as a plug-in to a program and colledting useage data. It's a class project with WPF windows.